# How to I get the value of the assignee tag from the following XML using Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell, selectnodes

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<work-item>
    <field id="assignee">John Doe</field>
    <field id="author">admin</field>
    <field id="created">2019-06-05 10:03:38.763 -0400</field>
    <field id="description" text-type="text/plain">
.
.
.
</work-item>
$singleAssignee  = $MyXML.SelectNodes('//work-item/field[@id="assignee"]')
write ("`t" + $singleAssignee)
```

Output is: field

```
$singleAssignee  = $MyXML.SelectNodes('//work-item/field[@id="assignee"]')
write ("`t" + $singleAssignee.InnerText)
```

output is empty(null)

How do i get the value of the assignee id (John Doe)?

I have also tried the following, both return nothing

```
#$singleAssignee  = $MyXML.work-item.field.assignee
#$singleAssignee  = Select-XML -xml $MyXML -xpath "//work-item/field/@assignee"
```

Answer (score 0):

@steve-gray That code is working for me, once I fix the XML. In your example the last `<field>` element isn't closed with a `</field>` tag. If that error is also in the actual XML, and you are not catching the error when you assign $MyXML, perhaps that is the actual issue?
Also, you are using SelectNodes, so `$singleAssignee` might not be so single. This might get you a little closer.

```
$assignees  = $MyXML.SelectNodes('//work-item/field[@id="assignee"]')
foreach ($assignee in $assignees) {
    write ("`t$($assignee.InnerText)")
}
```

Comment: Sorry, i omitted a lot of the XML. the field is closed properly in my file.  I added the foreach and it works. i guess that means the selectNodes returns a list and you have to go through the list regardless of how many elements are in it.

Comment: Yes, by using SelectNodes you get an array, potentially with only one item. And the array doesn't have anything in an .InnerText property, but because of how PowerShell works it also doesn't throw an error there. That and polluted pipeline issues can really be fussy to track down.

Answer (score 0):

Did you declare `$MyXml` as type `[xml]` ?
If so, both `$singleAssignee.InnerText` or `$singleAssignee.'#text'` would give you the value of the field 'John Doe' :

```
# using the xml as here-string
[xml]$MyXml = @"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<work-item>
    <field id="assignee">John Doe</field>
    <field id="author">admin</field>
    <field id="created">2019-06-05 10:03:38.763 -0400</field>
    <field id="description" text-type="text/plain"></field>
</work-item>
"@

# or if the xml is in a file, use 
# [xml]$MyXml = Get-Content -Path 'D:\test.xml' -raw # '<THE XML FILE>'

$singleAssignee  = $MyXML.SelectNodes('//work-item/field[@id="assignee"]')
$singleAssignee.'#text'
```

Comment: Yes, i didn't include the entire Powershell script, and i tried both InnerText and "#text". when i put the write statement in a foreach loop, everything worked as expected.